# GeoJSON in JavaScript

Tags: geojson, angularjs

I'm trying to read a geojson file to get the coordinates, but in this case I'm reading it as json but it sends me error (access-control allow origin).

This is the structure of my function

```
Lee() {
const url = 'http://ip/carpeta/datosG.geojson'
return this._http.get(url)
  .map((res: Response) => res.json())
  .subscribe(solicitud => {
    this.dts.lt = solicitud.type.features.type.Feature.properties.NIS;
    console.log("sms", this.dts);
  })
}
```

This is the structure of the geojson file that I want to access to extract specific data

```
  {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "name": "datosG",
    "crs": {
        "type": "name",
        "properties": {
            "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::32614"
        }
    },
    "features": [{
                "type": "Feature",
                "properties": {
                    "OBJECTID_1": 128472,
                    "OBJECTID": 290914,
                    "PERIMETRO": 0.0,
                    "X_COORD": 437737.6081,
                    "Y_COORD": 2134066.62689,
                    "ZONA": "0",
                    "MANZANA": "0",
                    "PREDIO": "0",
                    "EDIFICIO": "0",
                    "DEPTO": "0",
                    "CLAVEZONA": "0",
                    "DELEGACION": "0",
                    "SERMED": 0,
                    "NIS": 5018729,
                    "FECHA": "0",
                    "OBS": "0",
                    "FOTO": "0",
                    "NIP": 0,
                    "TP": 0,
                    "CAPA": "0",
                    "DUPL": 0,
                    "MOD": "0",
                    "REV": "0",
                    "D_CP": "0",
                    "SHAPE_AREA": 49.75133801,
                    "SHAPE_LEN": 28.561161905300001
                },
                "geometry": {
                    "type": "MultiPolygon",
                    "coordinates": [
                        [
                            [
                                [437741.79, 2134063.73],
                                [437739.25, 2134063.66],
                                [437733.569199999794364, 2134063.4821],
                                [437733.523299999535084, 2134065.245799999684],
                                [437733.454099999741, 2134067.901799999177],
                                [437733.411600000225008, 2134069.5347],
                                [437739.120000000111759, 2134069.68],
                                [437741.679999999701977, 2134069.74],
                                [437741.759999999776483, 2134065.51],
                                [437741.79, 2134063.73]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                }
            }, {
                "type": "Feature",
                "properties": {
                    "OBJECTID_1": 128475,
                    "OBJECTID": 23478,
                    "PERIMETRO": 0.0,
                    "X_COORD": 437644.56176000001,
                    "Y_COORD": 2134016.79904,
                    "ZONA": "0",
                    "MANZANA": "0",
                    "PREDIO": "0",
                    "EDIFICIO": "0",
                    "DEPTO": "0",
                    "CLAVEZONA": "0",
                    "DELEGACION": "0",
                    "SERMED": 0,
                    "NIS": 5018838,
                    "FECHA": "0",
                    "OBS": "0",
                    "FOTO": "0",
                    "NIP": 0,
                    "TP": 0,
                    "CAPA": "0",
                    "DUPL": 0,
                    "MOD": "0",
                    "REV": "0",
                    "D_CP": "0",
                    "SHAPE_AREA": 63.77637337,
                    "SHAPE_LEN": 33.4279660957
                },
                "geometry": {
                    "type": "MultiPolygon",
                    "coordinates": [
                        [
                            [
                                [437650.051900000311434, 2134013.946299999952],
                                [437647.240000000223517, 2134013.9],
                                [437639.22, 2134013.76],
                                [437639.089999999850988, 2134019.66],
                                [437644.519999999552965, 2134019.75],
                                [437648.129999999888241, 2134019.8],
                                [437649.897900000214577, 2134019.828099999577],
                                [437649.940499999560416, 2134018.2017],
                                [437650.009999999776483, 2134015.5458],
                                [437650.051900000311434, 2134013.946299999952]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                }
            },
```

I do not know if I change the structure at the time of reading since it is a geojson and I am willing to read it as json

Answer (score 1):

If you put your GeoJSON file in the same folder as your HTML file, and change:

const url = 'http://ip/carpeta/datosG.geojson'  to
const url = 'datosG.geojson'

Your HTML file will find the GeoJSON file and avoid the CORS error. You may need to rename your GeoJSON file to a .json or .js because your web server may not know what to do with a GeoJSON file.

You will also need to fix your data's projection to WGS-84 (4326) avoiding and issues with the mapping software.

Answer (score 0):

This is a CORS error. You'll have to handle CORS in your javascript or code. See here: http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/